# How do you say that variable is randomly chosen with a random distribution for range [3, 42]?

Tags: terminology, random-variables

This question is only about how to formulate something in English for a bachelor's thesis in computer science.

I have a variable $x$ which is randomly initialized. It is chosen from a (continuous) uniform distribution of the range $[3, 42]$.

My guess would be

> $x \in [3,42]$ is uniformly randomly initialized.

How should that be expressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that $X\sim U(3,42)$, then $x$ is a sample from $X$.